# pip - Use two requierements.txt files with two different index-url

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm trying to separate my python packages into two requirements.txt files: One for the public packages and another for the private ones.

The main requirements.txt file contains the following:

```
-r development-private.txt
-r development-public.txt
```

The development-public.txt file contains the list of public packages that should be downloaded from PyPI, like this:

```
public-package-1==1.1.1
public-package-2==1.0.2
```

The development-private.txt contains the url of the private index passed in index-url, like this:

```
--index-url https://a.b/c

private-package==1.1.1
```

after I run the command `pip install -r requirements/requirements.txt --ignore-installed`, the public packages are not reachable because the index-url applies to all the packages.

Is there a way to specify multiple index-urls in separate files?

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but what happens if you also provide `--index-url` with the actual pypi address in the public req file?

Comment: If that does not work, I think a better approach would be to just use 2 separate `pip` install  commands. It feels like it is the better practice anyway, especially if used in some sort of ci/cd process.

Comment: Use [`--index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-0) + [`--extra-index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-extra-index-url).